# CNAME okay for primary DNS record?

Tags: domain-name-system

I've setting up a Hosting service, as part of that service I need to automatically create DNS records in our nameservers for all the domains hosted.

Currently I'm using the following template:

```
;
; [USER] - [DOMAIN]
;
$TTL    604800
@    IN    SOA    [PRIMARY-NS].    [NS-ADMIN]. (
                       [SERIAL] ; Serial
                           10800 ; Refresh
                            3600 ; Retry
                         1209600 ; Expire
                           43200 ; Negative Cache TTL
)
;
@    IN    NS    [NS1]. ; Nameserver
@    IN    NS    [NS2]. ; Nameserver
@    IN    A     [SERVER-IP] ; Primary IP
*    IN    A     [CATCH-ALL-IP] ; Catch-all IP
@    IN    MX    0 mail
```

What I'm interested in knowing is, if I replace the primary A record statement with a CNAME to that server's DNS entry - will there be any adverse affects? This would make IP management on my servers far easier as I would only need to update one DNS record.

```
@    IN    CNAME     [SERVER-DOMAIN-NAME]
*    IN    CNAME     [SERVER-DOMAIN-NAME]
```

Is this a *good* idea? Or will this only cause trouble for DNS lookups on those records?

Comment: The data portion of a `CNAME` resource record is a domain name, not an IP address.  A `CNAME` resource record is a _client-side alias_, from one domain name to another.

Comment: @JdeBP Right, which is why it says SERVER-ADDRESS - IE: srv1.example.com instead of the IP address for that server.

Comment: No.  That (`srv1.example.com`) would be a server _domain name_, not an address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't do

```
@ IN CNAME ...
```

because the `CNAME` record type isn't allowed to co-exist with the (required) `SOA` and `NS` records that you have to have at your zone apex (or any other resource record type, for that matter, except for DNSSEC-related records).

See s3.6.2 of [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034):

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present;
> this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot
> be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be used
> without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

Comment: I'd just symlink the zone file for all domains.

Answer (score 0):

No! That wouldn't work as CNAME allow "domainname" in value friend and you can not set with your server IP. You can add 1 **A** record for the IP address (* @ XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX) and add CNAME record for **www**